# созданная функция Seaborn countplot не выводит нужных чартов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

Помогите пжл новичку. Вроде как бы все просто, но не могу понять почему так происходит 
Есть у меня датафрейм в котором 21 признак, один из них целевый. 
Часть их признаков - категориальные, часть количественные. 
Я хочу простроить зависимость категоритальных и количественных признаков от целевого с помощью countplot

Вот в таком виде, все работает хорошо:

```
sns.countplot(x='Partner', hue='Churn', data=data)
```

График выводится.

Но, поскольку у меня много признаков, я хочу написать функцию, которая будет по каждому признаку строить эту зависимость

Вот мой код функции:

```
def cat_countplot(data, hue):
    for i in data.columns:
        sns.countplot(x=i, hue=hue, data=data)
```

Применяю код:

```
cat_countplot(data, 'Churn')
```

Код долго выполняется и вместо того, чтобы вывести 20 графиков, выводит один 
[image: График]

Я пытался построить код только по категориальнымп признакам, но ситуация не изменилась
Как исправить код для того, чтобы выводились правильные графики в нужном количестве?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рисуйте каждый признак в отдельном окне и сохраняйте в отдельный файл:

```
def cat_countplot(data, hue, out_fn_template="{}.jpg", **fig_parms):
    for col in data.columns:
        fig = plt.figure(**fig_parms)
        sns.countplot(x=col, hue=hue, data=data)
        plt.savefig(out_fn_template.format(str(col)))
        plt.close()
```

Comment: спасибо. Помогло. Как теперь эти все файлы одной функцией загрузить скажем в jupyter?

Comment: @ivan100096, можете попробовать [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532894/ipython-jupyter-notebook-and-pandas-how-to-plot-multiple-graphs-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: @ivan100096 А почему вы не приняли ответ, если вы в комментарии указали, что он вам помог?